# How to add up numbers from 1 to N using a for loop?

Tags: javascript

This is the code I have currently, but it doesn't work! What's the problem with it?

It should add all the numbers from 1 to the base_number, but the code is not working.

```
function start(){
    var base_number = readInt("What is the base number? ");
    function adding();
}

function adding(){
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < base_number + 1; i++){
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
    println(sum);
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Please be more specific than *but it doesn't work!*.

Comment: The console says this: 
Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: @coder-croc ... you didn't feel the need to correct the "japascript"?

Comment: this isn't javaScript. and drop `function` from inside the `start` function

Comment: This looks like a disastrous conflation of two languages. You need to learn the difference between Java and Javascript.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry , thanks, that was the problem

Comment: @TinyGiant I did and was about to fix whole que. But user edited inbetween so I only used quick link of edit tag. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function start(){
    var N =  Number(prompt("What is the base number? "));
    return  adding(N);
 }

function adding(N){
   return (N * (N + 1)) / 2;
}
console.log(start());
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation on how this code solves the problem.

Comment: While this might provide an answer to the question, some explanation is required. Please update the question with some explanation of how and why this solution works.

Comment: Is You want add 1 to N numbers ?

Comment: He just applied simple arithmetic progression with `d=1`, then the sum of all till the nth term is `n(n+1)/2`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `base_number` to the `adding()` function

```
function start(){
    // read or declare base number 
    adding(base_number);
}

function adding(base_number){
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < base_number + 1; i++){
        sum += i;
    }
    console.log(sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "declear"? How do you do that to an identifier?

Comment: @TinyGiant I mean Declare the base number variable if he wants to. Fixed the spelling mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just fairly flabbergasted that you would think that this would actually assuage the concerns of the author. You must be joking right? (I'm not trying to be rude at all here)

Comment: @TinyGiant sorry, What I've I done wrong here? Please Enlighten me.

Comment: Well the OP is obviously dealing with a conflation of Java and JavaScript with a problem description of "it doesn't work". Honestly the code in the question looks more like it's supposed to be Java than JavaScript to me, it doesn't make any sense as a JavaScript program, where it _kind of_ does make sense in a Java context. You've focused on one single part of the equation in your explanation, then "fixed" the rest of the code for JavaScript, but it probably doesn't work for the OP even so because I'm fairly certain they're using Java.

Comment: But, I could be completely out to lunch. That is possible given the unclear nature of the question. Possibly something that you should have waited to clarify before answering.

Comment: Thanks, man, I got the point. Thanks for the suggestions, I will Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

`println` & `readInt` are not javascript keyword. Also when calling the function `adding`, there is no need to add keyword `function` before that

```js
var start = function() {
  var base_number = prompt("What is the base number? ");
  return adding(parseInt(base_number, 10));
};

function adding(base_number) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < base_number + 1; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(start())
```

Comment: Really? I am shocked that println and readInt aren't commands in Javascript. I am using codehs and they say these commands are javascript

Comment: (Java !== JavaScript) && (JavaScript !== Java) @Garry